# Sharepoint - Google analytics (New Users)

Tags: google-analytics

So a problem has arisen on my site when I placed the google analytics script on each of the pages, as when I log into google analytics its gives me incorrect data.

I know this because only 4 people have been given access (from London) to the site and in google analytics under "New Users" we have people from USA, Thailand, and other countries. Any ideas as to why we are recieving incorrect data from google analytics?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Referer spam ? Anybody can send data to an Analytics account. Check your traffic source reports. If all your users are in London use an include filter to allow only traffic from London only.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the numbers are incorrect.  Is the login page for the site exposed to the world?  If so, I suspect the majority of the unknown visits are people who hit the login page but don't actually login.

You should also check the Hostnames report to verify the code is coming from the expected website.  We've seen instances where a development shop copies GA code from one site to another and forgets to change the UA number.